# error: The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'Object'. (undefined_operator at [lets_chat] lib/view/search.dart:34)

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile-application

**this is my search.dart file getting error in this**

```
    import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/painting.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';
import 'package:lets_chat/services/database.dart';
import 'package:lets_chat/widgets/widget.dart';

class SearchScreen extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _SearchScreenState createState() => _SearchScreenState();
}

class _SearchScreenState extends State<SearchScreen> {
  DatabaseMethods databaseMethods = new DatabaseMethods();
  TextEditingController searchTextEditingController = new TextEditingController();

  QuerySnapshot searchSnapshot;

  initiateSearch(){
    databaseMethods
        .getUserByUsername(searchTextEditingController.text)
        .then((val){
      searchSnapshot = val;
    });
  }

  Widget searchList(){
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount:searchSnapshot.docs.length ,
        itemBuilder: (context, index){
          return SearchTile(
            userName:  searchSnapshot.docs[index].data()["name"],
            userEmail: searchSnapshot.docs[index].data()["email"],
          );
        });
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: appBarMain(context),
      body: Container(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 24, vertical: 16),
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  Expanded(
              child: TextField(
                controller: searchTextEditingController,
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.orangeAccent
                ),
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  hintText: "search username...",
                  hintStyle: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.orangeAccent
                  ),
                  border: InputBorder.none
                )
              )
                  ),
                  GestureDetector(
                    onTap: (){
                      initiateSearch();
                    },
                    child: Container(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(4),
                        child: Image.asset("assets/images/SearchIcon.png", height: 35, width: 40,)),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class SearchTile extends StatelessWidget {
  final String userName;
  final String userEmail;
  SearchTile({this.userName, this.userEmail});

    @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Row(
        children: [
          Column(
            children: [
              Text(userName, style: simpleTextStyle(),),
              Text(userEmail, style: simpleTextStyle(),)
            ],
          ),
          Spacer(),
          Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.deepOrange,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30)
            ),
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16, vertical: 8),
            child: Text("Message"),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**someone please help i will be very thankful to u :)**

**error: The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'Object'. (undefined_operator at [lets_chat] lib/view/search.dart:34)**

i will share other files too if needed please let me know about that
i am just a begginer so please help

Answer (score 0):

We are just assigning the result value here and not updating the state.

It is supposed to be

```
initiateSearch(){
    databaseMethods
        .getUserByUsername(searchTextEditingController.text)
        .then((val) {
        setState(() { searchSnapshot = val; })
    });
  }
```

Also, initially the value of `searchSnapshot` might be `null`
because of that `searchSnapshot.docs[index]` here we might run into error saying you have called `[]`.

**Tip:** Have a loading state which is false until it fetches from the database.

Like

```
bool isLoaded = false;
```

and while setting the state,

```
setState(() { 
  searchSnapshot = val;
  isLoaded = true;
})
```

Refer: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt

Answer (score 0):

there is a syntax error in the lines

```
        userName:  searchSnapshot.docs[index].data["name"],
        userEmail: searchSnapshot.docs[index].data["email"]
```

it should be

```
        userName:  searchSnapshot.docs[index].data["name"],
        userEmail: searchSnapshot.docs[index].data["email"]
```